# Explain the voltage drop curve of a set of lead acid batteries

Tags: physical-chemistry

Living on a boat and using batteries to power things over night, I've noticed that the battery discharge pattern seems to be a bit like a pyramid or the point of a sharpened pencil.

The batteries quickly fall back from 13.2 -> 12.7, and 12.7 -> 12.6 is faster than 12.6 -> 12.5 and by the time you get to 12.5 you seem to have hit the meat of the battery and further voltage drop is much slower, much like a pencil without a sharp point doesn't degrade as quickly as a freshly sharpened pencil.

We've never gone below 12.2, but I'm assuming at some point voltage starts falling faster, or maybe it doesn't.

99% of the load on these batteries comes from 2 refrigerators and 1 freezer and can range from 50Watts to 200Watts depending on temperature and how many are running simultaneously.

I'm curious about WHY the battery bank displays this voltage drop that isn't very uniform.  What is going on inside the cells that cause this kind of voltage drop.  What causes the battery to begin shouldering the load with less voltage drop around 12.5v?  I'm sure there is some chemistry behind the reason, but I don't know what that is.

Charging voltage runs as high as 14.4 during the day when the solar panels are refilling them batteries, and we are adding 3.3-5.2KWh/day to the batteries, depending on sun and clouds.

Comment: As you suggest, the answer depends on the electro-chemistry of the batteries. This question might get a better answer on Chemistry SE. ... The steep changes in terminal voltage might look smooth if you take readings more frequently, and might be caused by your fridges and freezer switching on and off as the thermostat dictates. If you provide your data, this would help us to understand the problem better.

Comment: The behavior of batteries can be (and is) approached from both side of the chemistry/physics divide, but it is a pretty specialized discipline to the point that the specialty battery manufacturer in my town hires from several majors including physics and chemistry for R&D jobs, but expects to train all hirees in the basics in house.

Comment: Basically the battery stores charge much like a capacitor. So when you are using the battery you're draining off the charge which reduces the voltage. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead%E2%80%93acid_battery

Comment: A comparison to a capacitor in this context is probably not warranted because the voltage on a capacitor drops linearly with charge, while batteries hold high (but not quite constant) voltage for a large fraction of a cycle before starting to drop rapidly only when largely discharged.

Comment: Ye, the question is about the non-linearity of the drop.